# Accessing raw files for MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-resources

I have a few raw music files that I'd like for a single MediaPlayer to play.  After many attempts I was able to get the MediaPlayer to switch between songs.  However, one of my raw files keeps returning a FileNotFoundException.  This is bizzare to me because I imported it into my raw folder just like all of the other files that work.  I also am accessing it in the exact same way as the other files.

Here's the code where I'm accessing the file (It's called victory_music):

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = CPU.rawToFile(Results.this, R.raw.victory_music);
```

And here's the code where I'm accessing the other files (where it actually works):

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = CPU.rawToFile(Results.this, R.raw.defeat_music);
```

And

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.battle_music);
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
05-30 16:20:24.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3151): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start        activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MainMenu}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/you_win from drawable resource ID #0x7f040003
```

I've tried cleaning/building, deleting the file and re-importing it, and even using a completely different file and name, but it seems like whenever I add a new file now it doesn't work anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So I found out what the problem was, though I'm not exactly sure why I'm having the problem.

It seems that I will get this error for any file in raw that is less than 1MB.  I was able to work around it by looping my sound files until they were greater than 1MB.

However, I'm trying to implement sound effects using SoundPool.  These sound effects are naturally very small.  All of them are less than 1MB and all of them are giving me the exact same error as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! I knew that I had made some sort of silly mistake!

The files that I had in raw were not named correctly.  They should be named "title.mp3" but instead I had just named them "title" since when accessing you truncate the file type at the end such as:

```
R.raw.title
```

This must have confused me and I ended up truncating my names in my raw directory.

I'm still a little unsure about why my wrong naming convention still worked for files over 1MB, however.